# Using an e-mail address as a HTML element's ID

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I have a need to use an e-mail address (e.g. a@b.com) as the ID of an element in a web page.  The problem is that HTML does not seem to like the '.' and maybe even the '@' characters being part of an elements ID.  At least when accessed from jQuery.

I can get around this by replacing the '@' with 'AT' and the '.' with 'DOT' (or more obscure strings) and afterwards reversing the replacements.  But of course, it is possible that the e-mail address already contains the string 'AT' and my reverse replacement will not work.

I need to change the '@' and the '.' to characters that are valid for a HTML element ID, but not valid for an e-mail address.  This means that when I reverse the change, I am guaranteed to get the original e-mail address.

Can anyone suggest any characters to use or point me to specifications where I can look for myself?

I'm using C# on the Server side to do the replacements.  I am wondering if there is a way I can encode/decode the e-mail address that results in a valid HTML ID?  This may also improve security.

Alternative ideas also welcome.
Thanks

Comment: This won't work. Valid email addresses can start with a digit, but HTML IDs cannot.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage that's not true. in HTML5 ID can be numeric.

Comment: It seems from what you guys are saying, that an e-mail address IS a valid HTML ID (at least HTML 5).  The problem could be the fact that I am using it as a jQuery selector.  I'll do it bit more investigation. Thanks.

Comment: For instance, if you apply a class of "email" to any element that you need to pull the email from and use the `data-*` HTML 5 attribute(s), you can most likely still accomplish the goal you are seeking without having to hack the email address into a jQuery friendly string.  Apply your jQuery handler to the `.email` elements and pull the corresponding `data-*` attribute to get the email address in question.

Comment: Tommy, thanks for your advice.  I'll give it a go.  It's just that I have many similar pages on my site.  All of the other entities have INT ID's (I just prefix them) and work fine.  I was just trying to do everything in a consistent way (even if it's not necessarily the best way).

Comment: Incidentally, I have found that the ':' (colon) character is valid in a HTML ID, yet invalid in an e-mail address.

Comment: @RobL I'm afraid that's not correct. `:` is perfectly valid inside an email address (in the *Local-Part*) if inside double quotes. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696

Comment: Thanks Roko. Looks like I will have to change to using the data- attribute as suggested by Tommy.